# How to remove Invisible Data Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I need to remove word icon PLD as I mark in picture but I don't have acknowledgement before this when copy data paste in google sheet the data PLD invisible.

Can anyone please help and guide?

[image]

Comment: from https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/14812/how-to-search-for-unknown-3-digit-characters-with-black-background?_=1587222194113&lang=en-US just search with regex by `008A` char and replace

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to regex search for the hex value of the character to do the replacement.

Here's the match:

[image]

Then replace:

[image]